# Playing a video in slider and then swapping out for an image at end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

So I currently have a video playing inside a [HeroCarousel slider](http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/). There is an image before the slider and another image after the slider.

My code:

```
<div data-time="8000"  data-prev-src="/media/splash/slider-left.png" data-next-src="/media/splash/slider-right.png">
  <a href="/island-careers/retail.html">
    <img src="/media/island/splash/now-hiring-splash.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
<div data-time="9000" data-video="true" data-prev-src="/media/splash/slider-left-black.png" data-next-src="/media/splash/slider-right-black.png" id="video">
  <a href="/catalog/island-collections/packing-list/">
    <video width="1275" height="557" preload="auto" id="myVideo">
      <source src="/media/island/splash/video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <img src="/media/island/splash/escape-splash.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
<div data-time="8000"  data-prev-src="/media/splash/slider-left.png" data-next-src="/media/splash/slider-right.png">
  <a href="/catalog/mens-resort-wear/classic-shirts/breaker-striped-red-linen-shirt.html">
    <img src="/media/island/splash/breakers-shirt-splash.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

So my issue is that the video is playing when the page loads. When the slide enters into view, the video is already at its completed frame. I want the video to play when the slide enters into view and not when the page loads. The slider adds the class `current` to the current slide so I started writing the following script in order to get it to play:

```
//playing video
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $play = 0;

  if($play > 0) {
    if(jQuery("article#video").hasClass("current")) {
      jQuery("#myVideo").get(0).play();
      $play++;
    }
  }

});
```

This script is not working completely.

I would also like to swap out the video for the image found underneath it once the video ends (the video should only be played once)

Comment: can you please provide a sample demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be using flags and listening to `DOMSubtreeModified` and `ended` event.

for starting the video only when the slide is visible, you can do

```
var canPlay = false, played = false;
$('.hero-carousel article').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
    if(played){     // flag to make sure it is played only once.
        $('.hero-carousel article').unbind('DOMSubtreeModified');
    }else if($(e.target).hasClass('current')){
        canPlay = true;     // flag to make sure, playing starts only when slide is current.
        var video = $(e.target).find('video')[0];
        if(video){
            video.play();            
        }
    }
});

$('.hero-carousel article video').bind('play', function(){
    if(!canPlay){
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }else{
        played = true;
    }               
});
```

and for hiding the video once it is finished, you can do:

```
$('.hero-carousel article video').bind('ended', function(){
    this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

#### [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f1bemopt/)